# Cannot read value from .txt file correctly

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So, I've been creating Discord bot for my server. I created the command "join-chat". So it creates a 'request' and sends it to the service channel.  Each request has an ID. The problem is that if I save ID as a variable, next time bot disconnects that number resets. So I decided to save the ID counter in file.
Here is the implementation:

```
    if (command === "join-chat") {
        let requestID = 0; //creating variable 'requestID'
        fs.readFile('./requestID.txt', 'utf-8', (err,data) => { //reading file 
            if (err) {
              return console.log(err);
            } 
            requestID = parseInt(data, 10); //and parsing string to integer
            //console.log('Read data succesfully!');
        })

        //requestID_num = requestID.replace(new RegExp('0'), '');

        const emb = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setTitle('New request')
        .setDescription('Request to add to chat')
        .addField('Who?', `**User ${msg.author.tag}**`)
        .addField('Which chat?', `**Chat: ${args[0]}**`)
        .setFooter('Request\'s ID: ' + requestID)
        .setColor('#fffb3a');
        requestID++;

        fs.writeFile('./requestID.txt', requestID.toString(), err =>{
            if (err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }
            //console.log('Wrote file succesfully!\n');
        })

        let chan = client.channels.get('567959560900313108');
        chan.send(emb);
    }
```

The problem now is that when I type in chat '.join-chat test', bot sends request, but ID is always 0, while in file it's 1.
Any suggestions how to solve this?

Comment: Try to print data just after the fs.readFile

Comment: I guess it's because your code will break at `.setFooter(...` because you didn't escape (`\'`) your `'` sign. Because just after you close the string incorrectly, you try to increment your ID and save it to your file -- but that never happens, as your code never reaches that point.

Comment: CodeF0x, added '\', but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common topic when dealing with asynchronous operation.

This reason that `requestID` is zero is because you are accessing it outside of the `fs.readFile` request which is an asynchronous operation. This means that the value of `requestID` is only 1 inside of the callback of the `fs.readFile` request and outside of it it is still 0.

To solve this, you have two options:

1. Put the code that relies on `requestID` inside of the `fs.readFile` callback. This way you can be sure that requestID is always set to the latest value in the file you are reading it from.

```js
...
fs.readFile('./requestID.txt', 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }

    requestID = parseInt(data, 10);

    const emb = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    ...
});
```

2. Use a the synchronous version of reading a file (Note that this will block all further operation until request is finished). This lets you skip using callbacks but is not generally recommended.

```js
...
const data = fs.readFileSync('./requestID.txt');

requestID = parseInt(data, 10);

const emb = new Discord.RichEmbed()
...
```

For more information on asynchronous operations check out some of the articles provided on MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous).

As a challenge you can also try to convert the first way into a promise.

Comment: Second method is much cleaner and simpler.

Comment: I used the second method and it works! Thank you MrBobby!